# PHP time() and end of DST issue - 1 hour after end of DST

Tags: php, time, dst

I have defined this code as such(simplified version for clarity) :

```
$fifteenMinsLater = strtotime('+900 second', time());
$now = time();
 if ( $now > $fifteenMinsLater )   {  
    mtrace("This should NEVER happen"); 
 }
 else {
    mtrace("This should always be the case");
 }
```

On 11/03/2013 2:00 AM  the DST ends for America/New_York and clocks turn back one hour to 1:00 AM.

When I run the above code AFTER DST ends (i.e. after 2:00 AM becomes 1:00 AM)  on 11/03/2013 and between hours of 1:00 AM and 2:00 AM the line:

```
This should NEVER happen
```

is printed. However anytime before DST changeover or after the new 2:00 AM onwards all is fine.

This has resulted in a major bug resulting in users attempting to access the function that uses the above code to miserably fail within that one hour right after DST changeover.

PHP 5.2.11.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Are you sure you haven't oversimplified? `strtotime` & `time` return unix timestamps, which as far as a know aren't DST aware  / do not count down 3600 seconds unexpectedly. Were you comparing representations of those timestamps rather then the raw integer timestamp itself? AFAIK, only leap seconds affect unix timestamps.

Comment: A echo of $now and $fifteenMinsLater will go a long way in solving this problem.

Comment: Site http://3v4l.org is great for testing different PHP versions. Only version [5.0.0 to 5.0.2](http://3v4l.org/C1UhE#v500) are returning invalid compare.

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime()` and other date functions in PHP do not take timezones into account. `DateTime()` does:

```
$fifteenMinsLater = new DateTime();
$fifteenMinsLater->modify('+15 minutes');
$now = new DateTime();

if ( $now > $fifteenMinsLater )   {  
   mtrace("This should NEVER happen"); 
}
else {
   mtrace("This should always be the case");
}
```

The following would be how to do it in PHP 5.5:

```
$now = new DateTimeImmutable();
$fifteenMinsLater = $now->modify('+15 minutes');

if ( $now > $fifteenMinsLater )   {  
   mtrace("This should NEVER happen"); 
}
else {
   mtrace("This should always be the case");
}
```

Comment: yes its true that they don't take timezone into account but that is the whole point. They use UTC unix time.  So adding 15 minutes to the same time() function should work either way as the derived time variables ($now and $fifteenMinLater)  but are int unix timestamps. I would give a vote to your answer(if I had enough reps) as using your first code above in PHP 5.3.6 yielded the correct result.  Using it on PHP 5.2.17  however shows the same issue which leads me to believe there is an inherit bug in PHP 5.2.x.  Thanks much!